# Question about nested CSS?

Tags: css

I have a box `center`, and I want to color that box differently depend on the page. I try this

```
#center {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;    /* CC padding */
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 11px;        
}
#backgroundRed{
    background-color: red;
}
#container {
    padding-left: 200px;   /* LC fullwidth */
    padding-right: 240px;  /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
}
#container .column {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

so then I would try this

```
    <div id="containder">
        <div id="backgroundRed">
            <div id="center" class="column">
            abc   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

however the background of the box does not turn to red, someone explain to me what did I do wrong? btw, I must have `class="column"`

Comment: Is there any CSS for `.column`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does: http://jsfiddle.net/Tuvzj/

Comment: Disregard if this is just example code, but if this is your real code: 1) you'd be better off using a name that describes what the outer box IS instead of what it should look like, in case you want to change it in the future. It would be silly to later have div#backgroundRed have a blue background. But if it's called div#navigationBox or something, it will still make sense. Same idea with div#center - describe what it is, not how it looks, in case that changes. 2) If this is truly per page, you might consider putting a class on the body.

Comment: @Deniz: yes, there is. Please check my updated post. @Nikita: you are right. I have a another `<div id="container">` outside. If I take that `div` out, it work. I updated my post. Can u take a look at it. @Nathan: Thank you. I will definitely keep that in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you wanted was this rule?

```
#backgroundRed div#center {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That means "if div#center is a child of #backgroundRed..."

Your example should make the outer div have a red background.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
#backgroundRed{
background-color:red;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It works to some degree with me. However, I think `overflow:hidden`, hide every thing else around it. I end up with a box, correctly color but everything around it disappear. +1